# How to call the c# class lib file with out reference the dll

Tags: c#

I have a class library called (service.cs).

I have WCF service both are in the same solution. Here what am trying to do, am trying to call the service class upload.uploading() method from my service contract in wcf and pass the value .

```
namespace MyService
{
    class MyService : IServiceContract
    {
        public void Insert(string Name)
        {
            if (core == true)
            {
                Upload(XmlFile);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
```

here is the sample class library file

```
namespace Service
{
    class upload
    {
        public void Uploading(string file)
        {
        console.writeline(file)
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usher, please add what were you trying to do, what error message are you getting from the compiler etc... It's hard to answer when the question is not clear...

Comment: @dtb and casperone sorry about that,not mentioned clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't very clear, but I'm guessing you want to call the `Upload.Uploading()` method that's in a class library.

The best way to do that is to create an interface, like this:

```
public interface IUploader
{    
    void Upload (string name);
}
```

and have the external class library implement it:

```
public class Uploader : IUploader
{
    public void Upload(string name)
    {
       // Do the logic.
       Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Now, use this code in your main program:

```
public void Insert (string filename)
{
     var classLib = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("MyClassLibrary.dll");
     var type = classLib.GetType("MyClassLibrary.Uploader"); //FULL NAME with namespace.;
     IUploader uploader = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IUploader;

     uploader.Upload(filename);
}
```

What you're doing is dynamically loading the class library (line 1), dynamically getting the type of the class in it via reflection (line 2) and creating an instance of it (line 3).

It's important to have it implement an interface, like IUploader, which is known to the main program so it knows how to handle it, how to call its Upload() method, etc.

Comment: Why actually to insert full name? When you can just look some sort of Attribute (custom) then you don't have to set any names, then you won't have any coupling between the name and the assembly you use.

Comment: One more thing you forgot about Dependency Injection

Comment: I would even avoid custom attributes and simply iterate over the Assembly's GetTypes() looking for anything that implements IUploader, but all this is a bit out of scope. First let the OP get familiar with the basic concepts of reflection and assembly loading, otherwise it's a big mess of code that doesn't make sense without context.

Comment: Agreed i also thought about interfaces, but it's restricts you only on  implementation of them. I would go with attribute.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan that's correct,am trying to call the upload.uploading and pass the string value,this class library in the same solution.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan,just curious what's the use of interface rather than calling like Nikhil Agrawal proposed ?

Comment: thanks a ton @AvnerShahar-Kashtan,the explanation helps me a lot to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
using Service;
```

before the

```
namespace MyService
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do..the title says without reference the dll? Where is the Service.upload class located? Same solution?

If so, you can reference the namespace with a using statement as Nikhil stated.

Example:

```
using Service;

namespace MyService
{
    class MyService : IServiceContract
    {
        public void Insert(string Name)
        {
            if (core == true)
            {
                var uploader = new Upload();
                uploader.Uploading(XmlFile);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}


namespace Service
{
    class Upload
    {
        public void Uploading(string file)
        {
             console.writeline(file)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: service.upload class located in the same solution.